# Drupal multi-site in an add-on domain?

Tags: multi-sites, subsites

How can I configure Drupal 8 with multi-site under an add-on domain using cPanel?  I'm getting a 404 when I browse to my subdomain after following these steps:

1. Clean install of Drupal to my add-on domain: `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal`.  I can successfully browse to `addondomain.com/drupal`
2. In cPanel, create a sub-domain at `sub.addondomain.com` with a document root at `/public_html/sub.addondomain.com`
3. Create the directory `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal/sites/sub.addondomain.com`
4. Create a `sites.php` within `public_html/addondomain.com/drupal/sites` that contains the following code: 
   `<?php $sites = array('sub.addondomain.com' => 'sub.addondomain.com',);>`.  File permissions are 644.
5. Copy `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal/sites/default/default.services.yml` to `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal/sites/sub.addondomain.com/services.yml`
6. Copy `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal/sites/default/default.settings.php` to `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal/sites/sub.addondomain.com/settings.php`
7. Remove the directory `/public_html/sub.addondomain.com`
8. Create a symbolic link in `/public_html/`: `ln -s addondomain.com sub.addondomain.com`

When I do all of the above, I get a 404 error when I browse to both `sub.addondomain.com` and `sub.addondomain.com/drupal`.  Why am I not redirected to the Drupal installation page where I can enter in my database info, etc.?  Is the error with my symlinks?  My server (cPanel) configuration?  My `.htaccess` under either my `/public_html`, `public_html/addondomain.com`, or `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal`?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I didn't read your question thoroughly enough and it was wrong.

Comment: Could the user who downvoted my question provide a justification? I'd like the chance to revise my question before getting dinged.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not the down-voter but it could be that it is a bit hard to say what the problem is without having access to the server to troubleshoot. It could possibly be a problem with server config & symlinks, it could be a problem with ownership/permissions of the website files and/or webroot folder (in my experience cPanel generally doesn't like you to do things like step 7 & 8 manually if it messes with the directory ownership), or it could be something else entirely.

Comment: Can you confirm that the 404 error is being returned by your main Drupal install at /public_html/addondomain.com/drupal? If so the watchdog log for that Drupal site should contain the 404 error. If so that should narrow it down to a Drupal multi-site configuration issue because it means that the server configuration is working correctly.

Comment: Also, make sure that your settings file for the sub-site doens't still contain the configuration for your main Drupal site. Otherwise Drupal will think it's already installed.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to point the document root of `sub.addondomain.com` to `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal`.  I did this within cPanel, which - if I understand cPanel correctly - is going to directly edit the Apache VirtualHosts directives within Apache's config files for my site (something I wouldn't have access to directly with shared hosting).

Answer (score 0):

You say this,

- Drupal is installed under `addondomain.com` in `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal`
- The document root for `sub.addondomain.com` is set to `/public_html/sub.addondomain.com`

If this is accurate, they're looking for files in different places. Make sure these two are setup the same (either with or without the `drupal` suffix).

---

> Create a sites.php within public_html/addondomain.com/drupal/sites that contains the following code:  'sub.addondomain.com',);>. File permissions are 644.

Move or remove this file. It's not needed with your naming scheme and it's simply adding another step to debug.

> ```
>  * For example, for a fictitious site installed at
>  * https://www.drupal.org:8080/mysite/test/, the 'settings.php' file is searched
>  * for in the following directories:
>  *
>  * - sites/8080.www.drupal.org.mysite.test
>  * - sites/www.drupal.org.mysite.test
>  * - sites/drupal.org.mysite.test
>  * - sites/org.mysite.test
>  *
>  * - sites/8080.www.drupal.org.mysite
>  * - sites/www.drupal.org.mysite
>  * - sites/drupal.org.mysite
>  * - sites/org.mysite
>  *
>  * - sites/8080.www.drupal.org
>  * - sites/www.drupal.org #THIS PATTERN WILL MATCH
>  * - sites/drupal.org
>  * - sites/org
>  *
>  * - sites/default
> ```

More info here, https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/17ebfff72673728bc8495d67f35061ad8bdcc299/sites/default/default.settings.php#L13

---

<s>> My `.htaccess` under either my `/public_html`, `public_html/addondomain.com`, or `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal`?</s>

Could you explain a bit more why you have .htaccess files under `/public_html/addondomain.com` and under `/public_html/addondomain.com/drupal`?

I think I get my last question (above crossed out, leaving for reference of others). You created a directory under `addondomain.com` for drupal, `/drupal`. Now you are trying to access it via a subdomain. If you want to access it without `/drupal` at the end you should update the symlink to `ln -s addondomain.com/drupal sub.addondomain.com`